# Maximum profit stock market algorithm

Tags: arrays, algorithm

for the maximum profit stock market problem (using either the O(nlogn) approach or the O(n) approach), instead of returning the pair in array A that gives the biggest profit, how can I return an array that gives the max profit for EACH day in array A?

Max profit can be defined as buying on day i and selling on a subsequent day.

Comment: What have you tried? Are you allowed to seek help for this homework assignment?

Comment: Other than the O(n^2) brute force, I tried to compare each element with the subsequent elements in the left subarray, right subarray, and comparing each element in the left subarray at the end with each element in the right subarray. Still not sure how to get O(n) though. I can get help as long as I mention it. I'll edit post to ask for hints as opposed to answers. Thanks.

Comment: Don't divide and conquer. You should be able to do this in a single left-to-right pass. There's an easy way to keep track of the best price and best profit you've seen so far.

Comment: Before we can help you, we need you to [edit] your question and provide: (1) an [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), (2) a detailed description of the error or problematic output you're getting, and (3) your goal. See [How to Ask](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Next time will do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with `O(n)` complexity. It's just a single left-to-right pass. The solution is taken from [here](https://www.interviewcake.com/question/java/stock-price).

```
public int getMaxProfit(int[] stockPricesYesterday) {

    // make sure we have at least 2 prices
    if (stockPricesYesterday.length < 2) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Getting a profit requires at least 2 prices");
    }

    // we'll greedily update minPrice and maxProfit, so we initialize
    // them to the first price and the first possible profit
    int minPrice = stockPricesYesterday[0];
    int maxProfit = stockPricesYesterday[1] - stockPricesYesterday[0];

    // start at the second (index 1) time
    // we can't sell at the first time, since we must buy first,
    // and we can't buy and sell at the same time!
    // if we started at index 0, we'd try to buy /and/ sell at time 0.
    // this would give a profit of 0, which is a problem if our
    // maxProfit is supposed to be /negative/--we'd return 0!
    for (int i = 1; i < stockPricesYesterday.length; i++) {
        int currentPrice = stockPricesYesterday[i];

        // see what our profit would be if we bought at the
        // min price and sold at the current price
        int potentialProfit = currentPrice - minPrice;

        // update maxProfit if we can do better
        maxProfit = Math.max(maxProfit, potentialProfit);

        // update minPrice so it's always
        // the lowest price we've seen so far
        minPrice = Math.min(minPrice, currentPrice);
    }

    return maxProfit;
}
```

A few other variants [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-profit-by-buying-and-selling-a-share-at-most-twice/) and [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stock-buy-sell/).

Basically, if you have a question on writing an algorithm I would recommend first check at [GeekforGeeks](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/), it's a great portal.

Comment: I need to return an array that gives the maximum profit(buying on day i and selling on a subsequent day) for EACH day, not just the overall maximum profit. Any ideas?